# C# URL Manipulaton

Tags: c#

Hi I need to get the URL part from the following(highlighted):

"https://mail.microsoft.com/owa/redir.aspx?C=LVZeVTBynU2TWqJn3eikmq8hz93ZltAIJhSEViL8PzPXMPs1hYengWVx89uXAYBSMXQoVZq2byw.&URL=**https%3a%2f%2fhyd2bifmdsfdfd.farrrrr.corp.microsoft.com%2ffms%2fbrandedsurvey.aspx%3fsurveycontextid%3d66469411-5860-4544440-a523-58e7977f91a6%26usl%3den-US%26usdl%3den"**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If this is `ASP.NET`:

```
string UrlInUrl = Request.QueryString("URL");
```

Else, you can use `string.Split()` function to split and get the 2nd item (index 1) from the array.

```
string newUrl = oldUrl.Split(new string[]{"&URL="})[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the url is a string, this is a way to extract a querystring parameter from the url:

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.test.com?URL=myurl&foo=bar");
var querystring = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query);

string parameter = querystring["URL"];
```